# Typesafe convertion of one object to another (aka pick)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have **a lot** of objects with known types and I need to convert those objects to other objects with known types like this:

```
interface FruitesWithNoCase = {
  brokenbanana: string;
  brokenorange: string;
  apple: number;
}

interface FruitesWithCorrectCase = {
  brokenBanana: string;
  brokenOrange: string;
}

const inputObject: FruitesWithNoCase = { // My input data
  brokenbanana: 'foo',
  brokenorange: 'bar',
  apple: 123
}

const outputObject: FruitesWithCorrectCase = { // Desired result
  brokenBanana: 'foo',
  brokenOrange: 'bar'
}
```

I don't want to map every object manually and it would be great to have some function that can accept an input object of type X and array of properties and return and output object of type Y, something like:

```
const outputObject = getAttributes<FruitesWithNoCase, FruitesWithCorrectCase, (keyof FruitesWithCorrectCase)[]>(inputObject, ['brokenBanana', 'brokenOrange']);
```

1. I **always** have input and output types
2. I **always** have list of properties I need to pick in camelCase
3. I **always** sure that `output[prop.toLowerCase()]` exists in `input`

Without types the working code looks like this:

```js
const inputObject = {
  "brokenbanana": 'foo',
  "brokenorange": 'bar',
  "apple": 123
}

const anotherInputObject = {
  "randomcar": "Fiat",
  "randomtruck": "Ford"
}

function getAttributes(obj, keys) {
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = obj[key.toLowerCase()]
    return acc;
  }, {});  
}

const outputObject = getAttributes(inputObject, ['brokenBanana', 'brokenOrange']);
const anotherOutputObject = getAttributes(anotherInputObject, ['randomCar'])

console.log(outputObject); // { brokenBanana: 'foo', brokenOrange: 'bar' }
console.log(anotherOutputObject); // { randomCar: 'Fiat' }
```

Please help to make this function typesafe. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```js
function getAttributes<T extends string>(obj: Record<string, string> , keys: T[]): Record<T, string> {
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = obj[key.toLowerCase()]
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<T, string>);  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really 'toLowerCase' keys of an object and expect it to ever be type safe. If you want perfectly typesafe the below is probably the best you'll get.

```
const inputObject = { // My input data
    brokenbanana: 'foo',
    brokenorange: 'bar',
    apple: 123
}

const outputObject = move(inputObject, ["brokenbanana", "brokenBanana"], ["brokenorange", "brokenOrange"])

function move<T, Old extends keyof T, New extends keyof any>(obj: T, ...map: Array<[Old, New]>): Record<New, T[Old]> {
    const copy = {} as Record<New, T[Old]>;
    map.forEach(([o, n]) => copy[n] = obj[o])
    return copy
}
```